# Google Analytic-/null page on 'User Right Now by Page'

Tags: google-analytics

what /null and why is it happening? can not understand problem to search

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that there is the slash `/` before `null` I am afraid that it could be a tracking problem. I mean that, for example, you are rewriting the page with Google Tag Manager or with some function in page and the result is `null`, therefore you are actually sending to Analytics pages with path `/null`.